# Query an XML document with multiple identically named elements in bash

Tags: python, xml, bash, xmlstarlet

I have found several questions somewhat similar to mine, but I haven't been able to adapt their solutions.

I have an XML document where there are multiple elements with identical names. I can't provide the exact document content but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729396/xmlstarlet-selecting-element-by-its-position-number?s=a2dbf31c4c4f4dd79d64d76df37632ae) has one which is equivalent:

```
<table name="XFile">
    <row sourceLineNumber="D:\bla\bla\">
        <field>Borderish.fo</field>
        <field>Documents</field>
        <field>1</field>
        <field>This line here 1</field>
    </row>
    <row sourceLineNumber="D:\blah\blah\">
        <field>Charterish</field>
        <field>Documents</field>
        <field>1</field>
        <field>This line here 2</field>
    </row>
</table>
```

I need to be able to do something equivalent to the SQL statement `SELECT field[3] WHERE field[0] = "Charterish"`.

If it helps, my document does seem to have a schema defined further down which maps each `<field>` value to a name such as "IP address"; I haven't found any information yet on how to use this mapping but I'm sure there's a way.

So far I have been trying to work it out using xmlstarlet; however, I also have the option of using python if that would be easier. Please consider my level in bash/python to be somewhat basic, and my level in XML to be extremely basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that you have an XML document containing this part (you should've been the one who provided simplified but still relevant XML) :

```
<table name="XFile">
    <row sourceLineNumber="D:\bla\bla\">
        <field>Borderish.fo</field>
        <field>Documents</field>
        <field>1</field>
        <field>This line here 1</field>
    </row>
    <row sourceLineNumber="D:\blah\blah\">
        <field>Charterish</field>
        <field>Documents</field>
        <field>1</field>
        <field>This line here 2</field>
    </row>
</table>
```

and assume that your XML doesn't have default namespace, then you can adapt solution provided in the question you linked to be using this XPath :

```
//row[field[1]='Charterish']/field[4]
```

Above XPath is a translation from your pseudo-SQL query :

```
SELECT field[3] WHERE field[0] = "Charterish"
```

Note that XPath position index start from `1` instead of `0`.

Comment: Got it working thanks to you! Noted about the code provision, won't happen again :)

Comment: You're welcome. I can see this is your first question, no problem :)

Comment: StackOverflow etiquette question: I've discovered a problem with this method because not every <row> has the same number of <field> elements. Do I add a note here or make a new question? (assuming I haven't found the answer elsewhere in the mean time)

Comment: P.S. found a solution - using the last() function - but still would like to know the etiquette :)

Comment: Open new question. You can get people involved in the previous question notified by providing link to new question in comment.